# Calling python script from PHP newer ends

Tags: php, python

When i call my external python script with phpseclib tru ssh. I can see that my python script, does what it should do and also finish, but the php call never ends.

I have setup logging on my python script, and can see that it finishes but it never returns the result back to PHP so the php call to python never ends.

It works if the call made from php to the python script is about 2 minutes but if it last 4 minutes i dont get a result back, but the php call never ends either.

I use below code to call the python script.

```
$ssh = new \phpseclib\Net\SSH2("11.111.11.11", 22);
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
$ssh->setTimeout(0);
$result = $ssh->exec("python /url_to_remote_python_file $site $keywords ", $output, $ret_code)
```

How can i fix that?

Is there a way in python to make sure that the result is pushed back to php with a terminate state or something.?

Comment: @IvanRubinson there u go :)

Comment: Code of the Python script itself too...

Comment: Thats a bit hard, its a script im working on and iam not alowed to put it up. The script works perfect in commandline and when i call from php and it only takes 2 minutes to complete it also works perfect. Is there a way to send back to php to terminate the call?